# Confused by java syntax

Tags: java, android, syntax

can anyone explain what this `|=` means ? Like in here:

```
   noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a short representation of the statement:

```
noti.flags = noti.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a Bitwise OR operator used as assignment

```
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

is the same of

```
noti.flags = noti.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the assignment version of the [Bitwise Or](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) operator, ie:

```
 noti.flags = noti.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

The `bitwise or` does an inclusive bitwise OR operation:

```
10110 bitwise or
01100
-----------------
11110
```

From the source code:

> Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if the notification 
>      should be canceled when it is clicked by the user.

```
public static final int FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL = 0x00000010;
```

This is [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) for the number 16. If you're wondering why we use these types of flags, it's because other flags will have representations:

```
 0x00000020
 0x00000040
 0x00000080
```

Each time, we go up by a power of 2.  Converting this to binary, we get:

```
 00010000
 00100000
 01000000
 10000000
```

Hence, we can use a `bitwise or` to determine which of the flags are present, since each flag is contains only one `1` and they are all in different locations.

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanation of what this expression you posted (probably) does:

Every integral type is represented as a list of bits. So `noti.flags` has a representation of something like `00101`. The `noti.flags` variable seems to be a representation of flags i.e. options of a class. This means every bit means something else and could make the class behave in a different way, depending if the bit is 0 or 1.

The `|` operator is a bitwise OR operator. `|=` is the assignment version of the bitwise OR operator. (Behaves just like `+=`)

Now `Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` is a constant for a single flag, possibly `10000`. 
If you apply bitwise OR (`|`) to `Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` and to `noti.flags` (`00101 | 10000`), the result will be `10101`. This result is now assigned to noti.flags.

The expression you posted basically just sets a new flag, called `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` to the flag variable `noti.flags`.